# Why does my PHP/FTP spider miscalculate disk usage by about 15%?

Tags: php, ftp, backup

I have a router with a USB port and an external USB disk drive and I want to use it for backups.

Unfortunately, the router employs SMBv1, which is insecure, and Windows refuses to connect. The router has FTP capability to the drive, but the instruction set is limited. FTP does not provide any df (disk filesystem) or similar capability to monitor disk utilization. The LIST command and therefore PHP ftp_rawlist() will not work recursively. ftp_rawlist() does provide accurate file sizes, but directory sizes are wrong.

I am trying to "spider" the disk via FTP using ftp_rawlist()

This PHP script seems to provide the needed recursion, but the space calculations are off by about 15% less than actual. What am I missing?

```
$directories = array('/volume1') ;
$sizetotal=0;

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

while (count($directories)) {
    $curdir = array_shift($directories);
    $directorylisting = ftp_rawlist($conn_id, $curdir );

    foreach ($directorylisting as $line) {
    //substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] ) : string
      $ftype = substr( $line , 0,1);
      $fsize= substr( $line , 29, 13);
      $fname= substr( $line , 56);
        if ($ftype == '-') {
          $sizetotal += (int)$fsize;
        } elseif ($ftype == 'd') {
            array_push($directories, $curdir  ."/" . $fname );
            $sizetotal += $fsize;
            echo $curdir  ."/" . $fname ."\t" . $fsize . "\r\n";
        } else {
            echo "not a file or directory! probably a link.\r\n";
        }
    }
}
echo $sizetotal . "\r\n";
```

Comment: if you can plug a usb drive in to the router, why cant you plug it in to the computer?

Comment: I can, but you miss the point. Several computers on my LAN all need backing up regularly, and automatically.

Comment: Filesystems allocate space in blocks of 512 (or 1024, or 4096) bytes so there is *"slack"* since a 300 byte file will need a whole 512 byte block. If files are many MB in size, the percentage is small. If files are tiny, the percentage waste can be enormous.

Comment: I added an estimator for directory structure (not shown) adding 1024 + the length of each file/directory name but it didn't make a significant difference. I will try to see what my my block size, and add that too. I am still trying to find out how to calculate the "administrative overhead" or at least estimate it. If I can come within 1 or 2 % that would be good enough for these purposes. I will say this, Windows and  WinSCP are both pretty close.

Comment: A cursory look shows directories reporting as either 4096 or 0 (?), and lots of files less than 4096, which I am beginning to assume is the default cluster size. So if I assume 4096 for all directories, and round out file sizes to their next whole cluster will that get me in the ballpark?

Comment: Doing some further experimentation, testing a simple directory with no sub-directories Windows reports size and "size on disk." My calculation for size (uncorrected) matches Windows size, and corrected for clustering matches "size on disk." WinSCP matches size.  Comparing a directory with 1 sub-directory all 3 still match on size, but "size on disk" begins to diverge from my corrected size. But when I compare a directory with more than 1 sub-directory Windows and WinSCP agree on size, but my numbers don't match either one.